# how to get some percentage from stripe payments flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I am new to payment gateways. And I am making an app using flutter, where users will make payments. I am using stripe for making payments. What I want to do is to charge the customer a small fee for their every transaction. Which will be the service fee. So let suppose User A sends money to User B. then a small percentage of the payment will be transferred to admin of the app and the rest will be sent to User B. I have searched a lot but didn't found any article or documentation about it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I doubt those business logic can be done in payment gateway. I  think you need to implement those logics in your side,

Comment: Thank you for responding. But what I have right now is one way which is that when the user makes a payment it basically sends the money to admin and then the admin has to accept the request from admin pannel to release the money from his side to the receiver. But this does not seem right. Do you have a better approach?

Comment: For me what you have done now is correct, you need to log, monitor and govern your app's transaction because it's crucial for your business.